# Could #include *not* be followed by <filename> or "filename"?

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor, misra

From [MISRA-C 2004](http://www.ristancase.com/html/dac/manual/3.12.02%20MISRA-C%202004%20Rules.html):

> 19.3 (req): The '#include' directive shall be followed by either a `<filename>` or `"filename"` sequence.

What is the alternative? Could `#include` ever be followed by something other than `<filename>` or `"filename"`?

Edit: Are they referring to `#define`d preprocessor variables?

Answer (score 0):

At least some preprocessors support a “computed include”, i.e., the `#include` directive may be followed by a preprocessor macro, which must (eventually) expand into `"filename"` or `<filename>`. So, yes, I believe this rule is to exclude such macro expansion in `#include` directives.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can actually use preprocessor macros for the file. See e.g. §6.10.2/4 in the C11 specification:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # include pp-tokens new-line
> ```
>
> (that does not match one of the two previous forms) is permitted. The preprocessing
>   tokens after include in the directive are processed just as in normal text.

The macro have to expand to a valid inclusion file though, so it has to expand to either `"filename"` or `<filename>`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my copy of MISRA C:2004 at hand, but my recollection is that  Rule 19.3 is the same as Rule 20.3 in the new version, MISRA C:2012.

The later includes the following amplification:

> This rule applies after macro replacement has been performed

As such, it is the intent that the following is acceptable:

```
#define FILENAME "filename.h"
#include FILENAME
```

The examples also show this as being compliant.

So even if MISRA-C:2004 Rule 19.3 is not explicit in this regards, MISRA C:2012 Rule 20.3 shows clarification.

Comment: It sounds like the MISRA rule specifies exactly the same requirements as the C standard. Is there any legal `#include` directive that the MISRA rule would prohibit? If not, what's the point of the rule?

Comment: The standard defines these as being the only two allowed, not what happens with other formats (undefined behaviour).  Some compilers allow (eg) `#include filename.h`

Comment: The standard permits either `#include <...>`, or `#include "..."`, or `#include pp-tokens`, where `pp-tokens` is a sequence of preprocessor tokens that must resolve to one of the other two forms. But a `#include` that violates those rules (surprisingly) does not violate a constraint or syntax rule, so I suppose the behavior of `#include filename.h` is simply undefined. MISRA C forbids using a non-standard form, even if a particular C compiler accepts it. (I've never seen a compiler that permits `#include filename.h`, and I can't imagine why any compiler would do so.)

Comment: I agree, Keith, but any such other forms are Undefined Behaviour which is undesirable. Hence the rule.

Comment: @Andrew: Historically, Undefined Behavior simply meant compiler writers were free to write extensions; if the standard authors wanted to forbid such extensions they could have indicated that programs using anything other than the standard forms were ill-formed; I think the purpose of MISRA's rule is to avoid having code be needlessly dependent on compiler extensions.

Comment: With respect @supercat that is not entirely correct. "Undefined Behaviour" is, er, behaviour that is specifically stated as being "undefined" (ie unknown).  Where compiler writers are free to implement something how they see fit is described as "Implementation Defined" - and compiler vendors are required to document their implementation.

Comment: @Andrew: If an implementation defined e.g. `#include -once filename1.h" "filename2.h"  ~"optional.h" "filename3.h"` as meaning "include the indicated files consecutively from path "path" if they haven't been included before, without re-opening the present source file between them, and don't squawk if `optional.h` isn't found", that could  be a useful extension for a system running off floppies, since some such systems have a limited ability to keep multiple files open at once, and each act of closing and re-opening a file could add 200ms to compilation times.

Comment: @Andrew: Further, if a compiler vendor wanted to make `#include easteregg` cause the compiler to output an ASCII art picture of a decorative ovoid to the console, that would be legitimate under the standard even if it was documented nowhere.  If handling of non-standard `#include` directives was "implementation-defined", compiler writers would not be allowed to include such undocumented features.

Comment: @supercat - both of your suggestions would be considered "language extensions" as they are additional features, over and above the standard.  And both introduced a non-portability.

Comment: @Andrew: The term "Implementation Defined" is only used to describe situations where compilers are *required* to have concrete documented behavior for something.  Since the Standard seems to have been written strictly from a requirements standpoint rather than a normative standpoint (with some unfortunate consequences for the language, IMHO) it makes no distinction between constructs/behaviors which should be considered invalid, those where certain extensions would be desirable when they can be provided, and those where compiler authors should feel free to add...

Comment: ...system-specific extensions.  I'm not sure when and why all forms of Undefined-Behavior got lumped together, or why people think extensions that weren't specifically contemplated by the standard should be considered Implementation Defined when by the wording of the standard that's basically impossible (since anything designated by the Standard as Implementation Defined *must* be documented, and the Standard can only require documentation of things contemplated thereby).

Comment: Surely, the purpose of the Standard is to standardise... anything extra is non-standard? Additional (implementation specific) features (no matter how useful) remove portability.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical example of a rule which is only there for the sake of the static analysers. The C standard states that if an `#include` doesn't follow any of the two standard forms, you invoke undefined behavior. To block that (rare) undefined behavior from appearing anywhere, through static analysis, they needed a rule.